# ignore keyError in list list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to extract all objects that have certain keys in a dict however some dicts do not contain all of the keys and I would like to ignore the keyError and keep going. I`ve seen some implementations of doing this with try and except but it will not work in my case

```
allValues = []
for dictionary in masterDict:
    values = [(dictionary[x]) for x in keysArray]
    allValues.append(values)
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? Should missing keys be skipped, replaced with a default value, ...?

Comment: if the key does not exist to just keep looping

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. Please show examples of inputs and outputs; should `len(values) == len(keysArray)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use a ***filter* statement** in the *list comprehension*:

```
values = [dictionary[x] for x in keysArray if x in dictionary]
```

So here Python will first check if `x in dictionary` holds. If not, then the `x` is ignored. Otherwise `dictionary[x]` is added to the dictionary.

In case you do *not* want to ignore these values, but **add a fallback value** to the list, you can use:

```
values = [dictionary.get(x,fallback) for x in keysArray]
```

where `fallback` is the "fallback value".

Comment: thank you for elegantly clearing this up I greatly appreciate it.